# How to generate a distribution build?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, distribution

Is there any document that detail out the process to generate a distribution build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had very similar issues trying to get started with publishing to the App Store and Apple did not make getting up and running very easy to understand so hopefully I can help with the very muddy waters you're about to tread through.

There are 3 main resources you need to keep in sync and those are the iOS Provisioning Portal, iTunes Connect and Xcode.

1. **[iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)** allows you to create provisioning
   profiles, certificates and App IDs that are used by Xcode and iTunes
   Connect.
2. **[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)** is used to create and manage your applications on
       the App Store.
3. **Xcode** is your development studio and can be used to upload your
       binaries directly to iTunes Connect. Xcode will also be the system
       that signs your binary with the security certificate you created in
       the iOS Provisioning Portal.

As of this writing there are at least 2 major versions of Xcode (3 and 4) being widely used by developers and the process varies slightly between the two, but before you even get into trying to build a distribution build, you need to first head over to the iOS provisioning portal to create your:

- App ID
- Distribution Provisioning Profile
- Distribution Certificate

You can get started with the information located on the [iOS Provisioning Portal's overview page.](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)

Note that you will need to have an active iOS developer account to access these areas of the iOS Dev Center and the iOS Provisioning Portal.

Once you've created the above items, you should be able to follow the instructions on the iOS Provisioning Portal to download and install your distribution profile and certificate.

After that you will need to login to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/).

Again, you need an active developer account to access these resources.

Once in, you will need to create a new application using the "Manage Your Applications" link on the right side of the page. When creating your application in iTunes Connect be sure to use the App ID you created for your App in the iOS Provisioning Portal otherwise the binaries won't match when you upload the binary from within Xcode.

If you are using Xcode 4 you should be able to follow the instructions on [this blog](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442) for building your project for distribution on the App Store.

If you are looking to do beta Ad-Hoc distributions to users other than yourself, I highly recommend using [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com) as it makes managing the entire process extremely easy and negates the need for your users to have to muck around with provisioning profiles, certificates or even iTunes in general (installs over the air). I just started using it the other day and I'm already hooked and it happens to be free so that's a big plus.

Comment: +1 Great detail! I've edited those links into the answer for you - you can remove the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look on iTunes Connect for details on how to do AdHoc and App Store builds.

Comment: There is a big pdf document available in iTunes Connect that tells all about distribution...